# What is the neuroscience behind copying dialect?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology

So everybody raised in the same area speaks with the same dialect, why is it so? What is the neuroscience behind this phenomenon?

Comment: isn't this more of genetics then neuroscience?

Comment: @Vicrobot People move from place to place far too quickly for genetics to be an explanation.